# Modelling count differences on irregular lattice

Tags: time-series, count-data, spatio-temporal

I have the following dataset. I have a time series over an irregular grid where for each  position in the grid, there is a variable that for each point in time counts the cumulative difference between positive events (+1), neutral events (0) and negative events (-1). In other words, at each point in time the events that can happen are an increase in the count, a decrease in the count, or not change in the count. It is a process for discrete time points, in discrete space and with discrete values. It has the following simplified form

```
      Position_1 Position_2 Position_3 ........
 [1,]         -1          1         -1
 [2,]          0          2         -2
 [3,]          0          3         -1
 [4,]          0          3         -2
 [5,]          0          4         -3
 [6,]         -1          5         -4
 [7,]         -2          4         -3
 [8,]         -3          3         -3
 [9,]         -3          4         -3
[10,]         -4          3         -2
[11,]         -3          4         -1
[12,]         -3          5         -2
[13,]         -3          5         -2
[14,]         -4          4         -2
[15,]         -4          4         -3
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

where each column represent a position in space and each row a point in time. The data also presents seasonality. The neighborhood structure is well known and defined across spatial points, and the temporal dependence structure can be assumed to be first order Markovian.

Are there methods to model these sort of spatio-temporal series, and are any implemented in R? I have looked into spatiotemporal processes for counts, but they assume that the random variables at each position take only positive values, i.e. counts.

Comment: This currently seems a bit broad, as you've only mentioned the type of data and the fact that there's seasonality. What knowledge or assumptions do you have about the dependence structure across space and time?

Comment: @user20160 thank you for your input. I will clarify in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now I'm wondering: how do you have seasonality if this is a 1st order Markov chain? Also, can you elaborate on the meaning of your spatial 'neighborhood structure'? What does it imply about dependence/independence over space?

Comment: What is the contrast between seasonality and Markovian assumption? By construction I would say the process to be 1st order Markovian, as the values are cumulative sums, thus depending only on the values at the previous time point. With regards to the spatial neighborhood structure, what I mean is that I have a known binary adjacency matrix. Neighbors are almost only first order, with some 2nd and 3rd order relationships then and there.